# Allow remote connection postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.4

I'm completed the installation of PG server.  I want to be able to be able to remote connect to it with pgAdmin but keeps on getting server don't listen error.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "192.168.1.11" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

It's on my network and I know I have to edit pg_hba.config file.  Everywhere I read, I have to add a line,

```
host    all         all         ip address/mask    md5
```

My question is, what is the /mask and how/where do I get it?  The IP I'm connecting from is 192.168.1.9.

Thank you so much for your time, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Postgresql 9.4.

Comment: `host all  all 192.168.1.9/32   md5` and put it not to the end, but to the begining of "host" section - just after "local"

Comment: You are likely to have /24 or /16 subnet. If you chose /32 it means only this address can connect.

Comment: according to your error message , look at your postgresql.conf listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: @RémyBaron i have listen_addresses=* on my file.

Comment: @VaoTsun , what is /32?  is there a logically way to determine it?

Comment: it means ONLY ONE ip address can connect. yours. look at http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/netmask-ref.html or any other resourse for netmask bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number after the `/` is actually not a mask, but the [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) mask length.

It states how many leading bits must match the IP address preceeding the `/` 
for an incoming address to match the `pg_hba.conf` entry.

If you want the line to only work for your host, use `192.168.1.9/32` (all 32 bits must match).
To have the line apply to all hosts that start with `192.168.1.`, use `192.168.1.0/24`.
To match all hosts, use `0.0.0.0/0`.